# xhtml add condition for label output

Tags: jsf, facelets

I want to add a condition on my webpage to check if the retrieved value is null or something else:

xhtml

```
<div id="topbarMsg" class="topbar-msg">
    <c:if value="#{Bean.loginCustomer}" test = EMPTY>
        <h:outputFormat id="welId" value="#{msg['label.welcome']} ">
        </h:outputFormat>
    <c:if test = NOT EMPTY>        
        <h:outputFormat id="welId" value="#{msg['label.welcomeUser']} ">
            <f:param id="paramOneId" value="First Name" />
</div>
```

java bean

```
private Customer loginCustomer;

public final Customer getLoginCustomer() {
    return loginCustomer;
}
```

From the code above, it will check the firstname if it is empty or not and from there it will call the proper label to print in the webpage but seems to be not working. anyone???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to give a conclusive answer without seeing your `Customer` bean and your actual messages, but should be somewhat close to this:

```
<div id="topbarMsg" class="topbar-msg">
    <h:panelGroup id="welId">
        <h:outputFormat rendered="#{empty Bean.loginCustomer}"
            value="#{msg['label.welcome']}" />  
        <h:outputFormat rendered="#{not empty Bean.loginCustomer}"
            value="#{msg['label.welcomeUser']} ">

            <f:param value="{Bean.loginCustomer.firstName}" />
        </h:outputFormat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<h:outputFormat id="welId" value="#{Bean.loginCustomer eq empty ? msg['label.welcome']} : msg['label.welcomeUser']} ">
```